# Cannot resolve eureka-client and eureka-core release candidates

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I faced a problem with com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:2.0.0-rc.4 [build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqkAC.png)

(Sorry for pom screenshots, was too much code here)

[pom1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts2SZ.png)

[pom2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4gvX.png)

[pom3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q3dG.png)

How can I resolve this dependency?

I tried to add a [dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYF1v.png)

But it didn't help.

Maven clean install and deleting .m2 repo also didn't help.

Comment: Images are still not the way to go. Setup a repo on github or the like to share more code. Without seeing your pom, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2022.0-Release-Notes#202200-m5

Comment: the solution provider must get everything easily also it will be easier to index if you consider providing the main part of the code in a code tag then you may also consider putting them in GitHub link. please don't misjudge my request in this regard but it is the forum policy. thx

Comment: @spencergibb your link is really helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding

```
<repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change spring cloud version(2022.0.0-RC2) to
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>

And Spring version to <2.7.5>